# Allow elastic to override allocation excludes in emergency

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple elastic search setup: 2 master/data nodes and a data node. Node `old-master` is on a server without enough CPU, so I used "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" to force allocation away from the `old-master`.

Now, `old-master` is functioning more like a coordinating node (date and master are both set to true still, but there are no shards allocated to the node.) However, if the `new-master` fails, I would like `old-master` to handle the shards that `new-master` would have.

Is there any way to allow elasticsearch to override `cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip` in an emergency?

Comment: There is no such thing. An exclusion is exactly and only that.

Comment: The a better option is there a way to dissuade elastic from ever allocating a shard to the `old-master` node?

Comment: What do you mean? There is no automatic setting that can allow and not-allow at the same time the shards?